# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^ndx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos x)^ndx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Prove that

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^ndx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos x)^ndx.$$

My work.

Let's consider:
$x = \frac{\pi}{2}-x$

So

$$-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\right)^{n}dx=- \int _{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos x)^ndx.$$

What did wrong that I am getting with $-$?

Comment: Note that the substitution exchanges the boundaries of the integral.

Comment: Hint: $\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(a+b-x\right)$

Comment: @Vega Thank you where I can find proof of that?

Comment: You can try to prove it on your own. Just substitute $u=a+b-x$, then $du=-dx$.

Comment: @unit1991 you can do it yourself with a substitution $t=a+b-x$ and the property $\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx=-\int_{b}^{a}f\left(x\right)dx$. More: https://www.shaalaa.com/question-bank-solutions/prove-that-b-f-x-d-x-b-f-b-x-d-x-hence-evaluate-3-6-d-x-1-tan-x-properties-definite-integrals_71135

Comment: I think [wallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) can help you.

Comment: @DarshanPatil Isn't that an overkill?

Comment: @Gary sorry I just read his title now I'm adding answer

Comment: @unit1991 Just wanted to let you know that you should accept answers( tick mark ) on all of the questions that you've asked.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin x)^n\mathrm dx$, Substitute $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-u$. Then $\mathrm du=-\mathrm dx$. When $x=0$, $u=\pi/2$ and when $x=\pi/2$, then $u=0$, so we get:
$\mathcal{I}=\int_{\pi/2}^0 (\cos u)^n(-\mathrm du)=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^n\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using Beta function,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^n x\, \mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}B\bigg(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{n}\bigg)$$
and
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n x\, \mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}B\bigg(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigg)$$
Using the relation between Beta and Gamma Function, both can be shown to be equal to:
$$\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\bigg(\frac{n+1}{2}\bigg)}{n\, \Gamma\bigg(\frac{n}{2}+1\bigg)}$$
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function